# How to get databound TreeViews selected TreeViewItem's Header section height without child heights

Tags: wpf

I am using a WPF treeview with couple of heierachical datatemplates. Treeview has a drag drop capability.

Can someone please help me to get the selected TreeViewItem's Header section height (Actual Height). If I get the selected items ActualHeight(TreeViewItem.ActualHeight) then it will give the height with the children. But I want is only the Header elements height. 
I achived this by using a VisualTree search to find a control (border) inside the data template which covers the entire header. What I want is a more faster way of doing this (Faster than the visual tree search) since I am doing this inside a DragOver event of the treeview.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that ActualHeight is the height with the children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TreeViewItem has a named part for the header called PART_Header, and you can use [ControlTemplate.FindName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname.aspx) to get a reference to that part.  Note that it could be missing if the control template has been changed and the new template does not actually render the header.

```
var header = treeViewItem.Template.FindName("PART_Header", treeViewItem)
    as FrameworkElement;
if (header != null)
{
    var height = header.ActualHeight;
}
```

(The Border you are currently using is probably the parent of this element, so you may get slightly different results).